# Banned from reviewing for approving an approved edit?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I just saw that I am banned for some days because of approving [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13975618).

I don't complain about banning when I am really "off", but what wonders me: When I check those links, all the reviewers approved; and I still can't find what's wrong with that edit.

So why exactly am I banned?

Comment: Messes up with the indentation and brackets placement and adds unnecessary quotes. That's an edit close to vandalism. All the other reviewers are probably banned as well.

Comment: IMHO, an edit reviewer who approves 6x more than they reject (or at least edit) after say 50 reviews should automatically be banned. All the original reviewers meet that criteria in this case!

Comment: I should also point out that your recent review history is very troubling: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13479465 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13202489 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13040188 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12921555 and that may bring more attention from community members and moderators to your reviews. I highly recommend paying more attention to future reviews, because carelessness like this can cause damage to the site.

Comment: @worldofjr I thought a while about your idea, and honestly: wrong approach. A) in my experience, many edits are OK. Maybe not all of them are great, but most are OK. So having 50 accepts can just happen B) more importantly, SO does **not** enforce "active editing". The job role is about *reviewing*. So your idea of punishing people that decide to not edit; or that just happen to run over "good enough" edits ... well, I would say: on the same level as my approval for that edit I linked to.

Comment: @GhostCat Well I did say in my humble opinion - it wasn't a request for SO to change it's polices. However almost every time I've seen a crazy suggested edit being accpeted, it was by 3 reviewers who have accepted almost all of the edits they've reviewed - presumabily seeing the (very obvious) review audit gotchas and rejecting them explaining why it wasn't 100% accept.

Comment: @GhostCat Given that you've been shown to have a history of accepting inappropriate edits, you should take the fact that you think most edits merit acceptance as a false assumption on your part.  Now that you know that many edits that you *think* should be accepted, shouldn't be, and that there is in fact a *much* higher percentage of edits that should be rejected in the queue, you should be considering that in the future if you continue reviewing edits.

Comment: @GhostCat Also, Worldofjr didn't say that you should be editing more, just that your acceptance rate is too high, and that more of the edits that you see would merit an action other than just accepting it, which would mean either rejecting it or editing it.  When you see an edit that's not appropriate you're not *obligated* to turn it into a good edit, but if you don't, you *are* obligated to reject such an inappropriate edit rather than accepting it.

Comment: @GhostCat Your acceptance to reject or edit rate is 924/80, so 11.5x accept to reject/edit. Judging by some of the reviews you've accepted I can only guess you didn't read the edit at all - especailly the failed review audits inserting random words into the question. We call this robo-reviewing, and it's very harmful to the SO community.

Comment: I think I get the message. But some questions: A) how does one find out about the rate? And seriously: are there any statistics / guidelines about reasonable rates? In other words: when comparing what better reviewers come up with; what is there average rate for accepting/refusing edits?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This suggested edit was reviewed incorrectly and probably all reviewers who approved it were banned.

This edits should be rejected because it introduces wrong formatting: backticks for something that isn't code, and quotation (`>`) for something that isn't a quote.

Comment: Formatting style with the placement of `{` (new line or not) is a strong reason also.

Comment: Not to mention the pointless reformatting of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. One question nonetheless: as all reviewers approved, when/how was that "bad review" actually detected?

Comment: @GhostCat Someone noticed and flagged the post for moderator attention, or it was noticed directly by a moderator.

Comment: Yes, all other reviewers who approved this edit were banned from review at the same time, as well as other reviewers who approved a series of related edits. This was part of a pattern of bad approved edits that we were handling.

Answer (score 27):

Edits should not add quotation markup to things that are not *direct* quotations. The text in question was not a quotation of anything; it's a summary of what others said. That's not a quotation.

The rest of the edit consisted of formatting changes. *Pointless* formatting changes; they merely represented someone's personal preferences for how code should be laid out, rather than genuinely fixing a problem.

The edit should have been rejected based on either of those, and every editor involved in approving it should have been banned for not doing so.