# Blocked from reviews, because my review was approved?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-suspension

Why is this edit "incorrect" if everybody, including myself, approved it?  Is this a bug?  The only theory I can come up with, is somebody disapproved of this edit but then had their review suspended.  I can wait out the suspension, but this sure feels like bag logic.

> A number of your recent reviews have been incorrect, including
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14429028. Please pay
>   more attention to each review in the future
>
> Come back in 3 days to continue reviewing.

Comment: The fact that everyone approved it doesn't mean it was the correct action.  It means all of those people did the wrong thing.

Comment: This is an *horrible* edit `that` never should **have** been *`approved`*...

Comment: It probably ticked-off a moderator and everybody got a temporary ban.  Pointless edits to ancient posts should not be approved.

Comment: There is some [advice for edit reviews on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539/168333). Should you decide to continue reviewing after the review ban ends, you may find it useful. Also, I proposed a [FAQ for editors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/812149) once; it's not official and aimed at editors rather than reviewers, but I believe edit reviewers can benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's incorrect because it adds entirely inappropriate formatting to the post.  "PHP" doesn't need to be italicized, "date" isn't referring to code, and so shouldn't have code formatting, quotes shouldn't be italicized, and there is no reason for the question at the end to be bolded.

There are also plenty of changes that should have been made that weren't.  The first sentence is noise and should be removed, as is the question at the end, and the block quote should really have block quote formatting, rather than being wrapped in quote marks.

No, this is not a bug.  You (and I suspect, the other reviewers who inappropriately approved this edit) were suspended by a moderator because of your inappropriate review.

Comment: Yes, all reviewers involved were banned by a moderator for a short duration, as was the editor. This wasn't the only such edit involved: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14429092 https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14429076

Answer (score 12):

It's not a bug, it's a manual ban by a ♦ moderator. The edit does absolutely nothing to improve the post; it makes it even worse by adding `code formatting` for things that aren't code, and should have been rejected.

It's basically the same case as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336405/banned-from-reviewing-for-approving-an-approved-edit/336406#336406).

Answer (score 0):

Being with the majority does not make the majority correct. There are plenty of examples of this in the Documentation review queue, which has seen quite a few edits approved, then rolled back extremely quickly.

EDIT: actually, I believe that I was the one who reported you, *with that exact edit* as an example. So yes, I am *positive* that you were manually banned, moreso than usual.

Comment: Does this really add anything that isn't covered by the other two answers (except a confession of some kind?)...

Comment: You don't need to know that you flagged the user to know that this was a manual ban.  The post would be listed as an audit if it were an audit, it wouldn't have multiple users listed as acted, and their action wouldn't be an approval, and given that it's not from an audit, it would have had to have been a manual ban.  That and the automatic ban reason is different than this.

Comment: @Servy I know that—I said _moreso than usual_.

Comment: @StephenLeppik So you're *more* than 100% sure that this is a manual ban because there's some possibility that you *might* have reported this user, although you're not sure, even though the other evidence is 100% certain?

Comment: @Servy https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri0Dc.jpg

Comment: @StephenLeppik So?

Comment: The Approve/Reject rate is not actually proof. The moderators want to see if there is a pattern. Show 3 or more recent reviews. Everybody can mis-click or have a momentarily lapse of judgment. The mods are best helped when they can see patterns of bad reviewing, rather than circumstantial evidence.

Comment: @S.L.Barth thanks, didn't know that. Good to know.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'm fine with the restriction, just wanted to be sure it wasn't some kind of system fluke.